# Многомерный IEnumerable в многомерный массив float[,,]

Tags: c#

Как пересобрать такой многомерный `IEnumerable` в многомерный массив `float[1,37,12]` ?

Что является переключателем для `for` ?

`ToArray()` только в одномерный переносит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IEnumerable` это перечислимое, оно не может быть скольки-то мерным, вы что-то перепутали. В реальности output не `IEnumerable`, у него реальный тип есть. Покажите код. И зачем вам вообще в массив это копировать? Здесь же простым подсчетом индексов можно напрямую к данным обращаться через `.Buffer`. Есть еще `.Strides`, но вы не показали, что там.

Окей, давайте в лоб.

Вот вы сделали

```
float[] array = <...>.ToArray();
```

Теперь создайте 3D массив

```
float[,,] array3D = new float[1, 37, 12];
```

И скопируйте данные

```
Buffer.BlockCopy(array, 0, array3D, 0, 1 * 37 * 12 * sizeof(float));
```

Готово.

Это просто, но есть недостаток данного подхода, все данные вы копируете дважды - сначала в одномерный массив, затем в трехмерный. С большой вероятностью в этом нет необходимости, но так как вы не дали никакой информации, зачем это и откуда взялось - других решений здесь найти невозможно. Гадание по скриншотам - так себе занятие.

Comment: aepot - извините за недостаточноcть кода, я пытаюсь действовать по этому мануалу https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/tutorials/csharp/resnet50_csharp.html тут `output` они превращают в `IEnumerable`, но сама модель у нас другая и видимо мне по другому надо действовать.

Comment: @Vipz в таком случае речь наверное о `Tensor<float>`, а не об `IEnumerable`?

Comment: `Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime.Tensors.DenseTensor`1[System.Single]` приходит от модели `var otput = results.First().Value;`, а мне как то надо его превратить в `3D` массив для использования через `Python`, либо в `Tensorflow.Tensor` для передачи в `Tensorflow.ctc_Ops ctc_greedy_decoder()` в `C#`

Comment: @Vipz `var` можно заменить на `DenseTensor<float>` или `Tensor<float>`. Теперь можно обращаться к `.Buffer` по индексу и `.Dimaensions`. А дальше смотря что вам нужно. То есть `.Value` это и есть `Tensor<float>`, его не надо превращать.

Comment: мда, что то заплутал), не знал что так можно, спасибо! `Tensor<float> otput = (Tensor<float>)results.First().Value;`

Comment: @Vipz в 3Д массиве вы обращаетесь по координатам `[z, y, x]`, в планарном массиве с этими же данными, то есть в `.Buffer`, можно обращаться через умножение координат на размерность, простая математика.